# Background Worker's ReportProgress percentage argument C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Is there a way to supply `Double` variable type to `ReportProgress` method of `Background Worker` so that the percentage is displayed with decimal points? (eg. 12.07%) Or should I simply pass it as a `UserState` argument and then cast it?
Wouldn't it be better to allow `Double` type on this method by default?

Comment: Honestly I do not think anyone is interested to .01 (or even  . 1)  in progress percentage...seriously, if it's so long (where . 1 may mean 10 minutes and constant feedback is vital... ) then single progress is not what you need.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I don't understand your statement. The task might take few hours and I believe the decimal points do give a better idea of what's happening. Sometimes people cancel the task when they see the progress bar stuck on 1% for a while

Comment: I'd post this on UX more than SO but: decimals are clutter, they don't give you more meaningful information and you want them changing just because user will see **something happens**. I'd keep progress integer and add another visual feedback. Task name, step name, task/sub-task progress. Anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to pass numbers between 0 and 10000, instead of 0 to 100.

Then you divide them by `100d` to get 2-decimal-precision percents.

Some times I find myself even passing enum values instead of percents.

Comment: Nice. I believe that's what I'll end up doing

Comment: I don't but I'd downvote for last paragraph...I don't agree to _misuse_ a poor integer that should be a percentage but...an enum?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I agree, but as long as it is self-contained, I can forgive. Another option is to use the `UserState` instead. A third option is to wrap `BackgroundWorker` with a generic class, which will allow you to have any type as progress (or arguments). The last option will inevitably use the `UserState` itself.

Comment: Yes, I was kind of ironic and I'm not so strict but I'd really go with the other options. Well actually I wouldn't use decimals just to give feedback of _something changing_ (elapsed time, time left, task's step labels, split into shorter tasks, a repetitive visual feedback) but that's another story (off-topic for SO)...

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) there is no BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress method overload which takes `Double` progress percentage.

And I don't see any need for this.

But there are couple of ways to make it **if you really need**:

1. Pass integer in format like `956` (95.6%) and simply divide when you are displaying it.
2. Use `userState` argument.